# Divide page into two sections

Tags: html, xhtml, html4

I want to divide my page into two sections. It must be separated by a slider. In the left-pane, I want to display Form names and on the right-pane, I want to show the Form that was selected from the left-pane.

Which controls to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking about using a [frameset](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp) (* shudder *)?

I know you don't have the jQuery tag, or even javascript for that matter, but this [jQuery Splitter Plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/) may do the trick... I'm sure you can expand the content to fit the page.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for [Coda Slider](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/)?

Comment: That's cool, I will definitely give it a try. But at present I require something like Split Panes.